# How to download a large zip file > 25 GB using Python?

Tags: python, http, ubuntu, python-requests, request

I am trying to download [this file of 25+ GB](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/awsaf49/coco-2017-dataset?sort=votes). The problem is that I don't have enough memory to fit it into RAM and while downloading it with chrome, I get connection errors.

I used the `cli` command as `kaggle datasets download -d awsaf49/coco-2017-dataset` but it gave me error  as:

```
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
```

I tried working with:

```
import requests 
from tqdm import tqdm

URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-data-sets/857191/1462296/bundle/archive.zip?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=gcp-kaggle-com%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220502%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220502T123414Z&X-Goog-Expires=259199&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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"

def get_size(url):
    response = requests.head(url)
    size = int(response.headers['Content-Length'])
    return size

def download_file(url):
    local_filename = "./archive.zip"
    total_size = get_size(url) # total size in bytes
    chunk_size = 100000000 # size of 1 chunk to download 100000000 = 100 MB
    
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size = chunk_size), total  = total_size // chunk_size): # Download a 100 mb chunk
                #if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename


download_file(URL)
```

After 4.3 GB of file, gives me the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7289/2178583065.py in <module>
     24 
     25 
---> 26 download_file(URL)

/tmp/ipykernel_7289/2178583065.py in download_file(url)
     20             for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size = chunk_size), total  = total_size // chunk_size): # Download a 100 mb chunk
     21                 #if chunk:
---> 22                 f.write(chunk)
     23     return local_filename
     24 

OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
```

What is the solution to that? I'm using `Ubuntu 20` with `Python 3.7`

Comment: The problem is in file system *(probably FAT32)* which limits maximum file size. There's no solution of this problem other than use another file system.

Comment: You can write each chunk to a separate file, but then you'll have to write your own code to read from one file after another if you want to decompress the file. (And the decompressed data will have to be written to multiple files in chunks as well.)

Comment: @chepner What are you suggesting? Like creating `n` parts of the whole, (say 268), save each part in the disc, open in a loop and merge? Is this possible? If yes, can you please provide me some help here?

Comment: @OlvinRoght But once I downloaded the whole file in one go with `chrome`. It's failing since then.

Comment: If you need 25GB files, I would *strongly* suggest focusing your efforts on getting a file system that can handle them.

Comment: @Deshwal, I doubt that you downloaded it on same drive. If file system doesn't allow files over some fixed size - you can't bypass it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Oh yeah so I'm transferring it to a backup, tried downloading it on the same drive. Switching to windows for the transfer on the unzipped files. Thanks for the insights.